# Error occurs when trying to build in eloquent

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I recently tried to update my ROS2 version from dashing to eloquent. I do have a good number of publishers and all are building without any problem. But one of them gives me an error which I cannot resolve. Can anyone give me a clue on what the problem could be?

`error: no matching function for call to 'rclcpp::Publisher<common::msg::Stanag4586Wrapper_<std::allocator<void> > >::publish(std::shared_ptr<common::msg::Stanag4586Wrapper_<std::allocator<void> > >&)'`

I am building with `colcon build`.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375997/error-occurs-when-trying-to-build-in-eloquent/) by [fnax8902](https://answers.ros.org/users/73234/fnax8902/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2021-04-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sgvandijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/72841/sgvandijk/) on 2021-04-12**:
It would be helpful if you supply the code where you try to call `publish` and where you create the publisher (ideally an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as well as the full error message instead of just a single line of it. Without that context it's very difficult to get a clue

**Comment by [fnax8902](https://answers.ros.org/users/73234/fnax8902/) on 2021-04-12**:
In Header-file: `rclcpp::Publisher<common::msg::Stanag4586Wrapper>::SharedPtr pub_stanag_u2g_;`

```
void U2gLink::init_publisher()
{
  pub_stanag_u2g_ = this->create_publisher<common::msg::Stanag4586Wrapper>("/stanag/u2g", 10);
}

void U2gLink::some_void()
{
    auto msg = std::make_shared<common::msg::Stanag4586Wrapper>();
    pub_stanag_u2g_->publish(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://docs.ros2.org/eloquent/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1Publisher.html

As the docs show, you can either publish a message or a unique pointer to a message, but not a shared pointer.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fnax8902](https://answers.ros.org/users/73234/fnax8902/) on 2021-04-12**:
Okay, and I guess in ROS2 Dashing shared pointers were accepted as well, right?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2021-04-12**:
Correct. If this answers your question can you mark this answer as correct to remove from unanswered questions queue?